# How to limit an array to a particular size (in kilobytes)

Tags: c++, c

In a particular situation I need to have variable (character array or std:string) where the size should not be more than 10 kB.

How can I limit the size of this variable?

Comment: What you want is not possible in a clean, straightforward, easy to maintain way in C++. You could wrap a template around std::string like unwind suggests and override `append` but since that's not a virtual function, you must can't just derive and overload, you must write a __lot__ of code to restore the original behaviour. Or you can use a custom allocator that will fail (i.e. throw `std::bad_alloc`) above some limit. This will work, but probably not the way you want. Finally you can do as Polynomial suggests, but that's not C++. You probably want to just check length before appending...

Comment: Thinking about it, you actually _can_ just override a single function even though it's not virtual... but I still wouldn't like to use such a thing, it feels ungood.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just don't resize it to be more than the size limit:

```
char* realloc_lim(char* data, int new_count, bool &ok)
{
    if(sizeof(char) * new_count > SIZE_LIMIT)
    {
        ok = false;
        return null;
    } else {
        ok = true;
        return (char*)realloc((void*)data, sizeof(char) * new_count);
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
bool allocation_ok = false;
int newsize = readint(); // read the size as an int from somewhere
buffer = realloc_lim(buffer, newsize, &allocation_ok);
if(!allocation_ok)
{
    printf("Input size was too large!\n");
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is always 1, by definition. Even when a char is 32 bits, `sizeof(char)` will be 1 (but CHAR_BITS will be 32).

Comment: @Sjoerd - The reason I placed `sizeof(char)` in there is because it's easy to swap it out for `wchar_t`, `FILETIME`, or any number of different types.

Comment: You don't need that inelegant `bool &ok` parameter. You can just check the return value for `null`.

Comment: @TonyK - In that case, you couldn't tell the difference between a size limit and a failed `realloc` call. I certainly would want to handle them differently.

Comment: @Polynomial Fair enough. However, in that case you should add the sizeof(char) to the realloc call as well...

Comment: @Sjoerd - Whoops! Missed that one! Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: What is this `bool &ok`? My C compiler chokes on it. According to the usage, it should be `bool *ok`.

Comment: @Sjoerd the `&` is a reference. This is C++ code. You can substitute with a pointer that you must de-reference as in `*ok = true;` to compile also in C.

Comment: @LucaMartini This is not C++ code. It might be good C code, but it is very bad C++ code.

Comment: @Sjoerd I was not judging the code, I was only telling which language was written in.

Comment: @Sjoerd - "not C++ code" is mutually exclusive of "very bad C++ code".

Comment: Shouldn't `realloc()` store the result to a temporary so you don't leak in case of failure?

Comment: @Polynomial If you intended this as C++ code, why don't you (1) use a template instead of `char`, (2) Use realloc() when it could have been created by `new` (3) Wrap it up in a class, to ensure proper deallocation, (4) Pass `data` by reference as well, (5) throw an excepion on failure, (6) use `static_cast<>` instead of C-style casts, (7).... There are so many wrongs with this code when interpreted as C++ code, you must be kidding to suggest this is C++ code. While it is fine C code.

Comment: @Sjoerd Writing good C++ code is not using all the C++ features that C lacks in every piece of code. For instance, (4) and (5) are not necessary to make the code good.

Answer (score 4):

For a character array, just do

```
char ten_k[10240];
```

It's not as if character arrays in C ever grow automatically, so I'm having a hard time seeing how this can be a problem for you.

In C++, you probably need to wrap a standard string type to implement the limit. This is often done as a template class, i.e. you'd have something like:

```
LimitedString<10240> ten_k;
```

Of course, this is a bit backwards; it'd make more sense to incorporate the limit to whatever code generates the string in the first place, since that code probably knows what to do when the limit is hit.

Comment: Pretty sure OP wants to limit the size, rather than declare with a fixed size.

Comment: +1 for suggesting to impose the limit inside the string generating code and using the normal type (char* or std::string) in the rest of the code.

Answer (score 4):

C++ doesn't provide a mechanism for that. However, you could implement your own freestanding `myresize` function which would do something like this:

```
bool myresize(std::string& s, int newSize)
{
     if(newSize > maxSize)
       return false;
     s.resize(newSize);
     return true;
}
```

You could write similar functions for `push_back`, `append`, etc

Of course it should be your responsibility to call these functions rather than strings members.